# Trying to understand Le's "cat paper"

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

QV Le et al. show in [Building high-level features using large scale unsupervised learning (2012)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.6209) how to use unsupervised learning of a deep neural net to recognize faces and cats. Working through this paper, I have a few questions:

1) Their neural net has an input layer (200x200 pixels times 3 channels) and then nine layers on top of it, and I wonder how large these layers are. It is mentioned that each of the nine layers has 8 "maps". Does this mean that the layers all have size 200x200x8? Their pictures seem to suggest that deeper layers are smaller.

2) In section 3.3 on p.3, they say "During learning, the parameters of the
second sublayers (H) are fixed to uniform weights". Does this mean that the second sublayer parameters are never changed and always stay uniform? Or is there a later training phase where those parameters are changed? I suspect the latter, because on p.4 they talk about "distributing the local weights W1, W2 and H to different machines."

3) Their objective function (formula (1) on p.4) contains the term $\sqrt{\epsilon+H_j(W^T_1 x^{(i)})^2}$ which I cannot parse. Do they mean $\sqrt{\epsilon+(H_j W^T_1 x^{(i)})^2}\ $? I would think not, because the pooling layer neurons output the $L^2$-norm of their weighted inputs, and that's not what this formula describes. Maybe they use the notation $(v)^2$ for the vector of squared components of the vector $v$?

Comment: This looks to me like it should be three separate questions. They don't seem very closely related except that they're about the same paper.